# What's the benefit of inline function calls?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Functions with no name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11304566/functions-with-no-name)

I saw this code (explicly it's in jQuery, with modification)

```
(function(window,undefined){
    var jQuery=(function(){
        var jQuery=something;
        jQuery.xxx=xxx;
        //...
        return jQuery;
    })();
    //...
    window.jQuery=window.$=jQuery;
})(window);
```

While I understand wrapping code in a inline function call can clearly define the variable scope, I don't understand the benefits of

1. passing `window` with a parameter instead of using it directly,
2. getting an instance of `undefined` by a undefined parameter, and also
3. defining `jQuery` by the return value of another inline function call (isn't that defining it directly is better with less code?).

Can somebody explain a bit?

Comment: You have 2 questions with same content: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11304566/functions-with-no-name ?

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate, I think I pressed submit button but it didn't load, and in my profile this question was missing (as I saw) so I re-posted it